# persisting an ArrayList in Python

Tags: python, numpy, openpyxl

Basically I have a simple employee list file and I am trying to load it in python and manipulate some data.

My code at the moment looks like this:-

```
from typing import Any

import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = load_workbook('Employees.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
row_count = ws.max_row
column_count = ws.max_column

headings_PlayersSheet = ['Name'] + ['Age'] + ['Nationality']


def get_employee_list():
    employee_list = []
    # get an array of players from the sheet provided
    for row in range(2, row_count + 1):
        # print(ws.cell(row, 1).value)
        employee_list.append(ws.cell(row, 1).value)
        # playersList.append(ws.cell(row, 1).value)
        for col in range(2, column_count + 1):
            char = get_column_letter(col)
            employee_details = [ws[char + str(1)].value, ws[char + str(row)].value]
            employee_list.append(employee_details)

    # print(employee_list)
    employee_list_arr = np.array(employee_list, dtype=object)
    # print(employee_list_arr)
    np.save('employeeList.npy', employee_list_arr)
    return


get_employee_list()
employees_list = np.load('employeeList.npy', allow_pickle=True)

# print(employees_list)
# print(employees_list[0])
# print(employees_list[37][1])
# print(employees_list[38][1])
# print(employees_list[39][1])
```

The problem I am facing is that when I do the last print(employees_list), I am only getting the last record, instead of the whole arraylist. I am fairly new to Python so I am trying to figure out how I can persist this arraylist so that I can use it outside of the function.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You are initializing the list `employee_list: list[Any] = [ws.cell(row, 1).value]` with every iteration of the loop. Simply move this line to be before the loop (or more correctly, a new line `employee_list = []` and convert the one above to `employee_list.append(ws.cell(row, 1).value)`)

Comment: I have already tried that but this will display the first record instead of the last.  So I moved employee_list = [] underneath the function def and appended but I m only getting the first record

Comment: Why are you printing and saving to the file ***inside*** the loop as well? Should probably be oustide

Comment: IIUC, the lines starting with `print(employee_list); employee_list_arr = ...` should be outside the for loop `for row in range(2, row_count + 1):` (otherwise `np.save` is just for the last row.

Comment: I edited my code above to do the changes you suggested, but I am still getting the first record only

Comment: ok I understand what is happening, I am getting all 5 records inside of 1 array

Comment: Please, please, please stop using `ws[char + str(1)]` in any kind of loop. The openpyxl documentation tells you how to avoid this.

Comment: @CharlieClark ok will look into that

Comment: Ok I can consider my problem solved, I will edit my code with the solution.  Basically I added another array so that I can have 5 arrays with the 5 records I am after

Answer (score -1):

I have added an extra array to get all the records in an array collection

```
from typing import Any

import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = load_workbook('Employees.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
row_count = ws.max_row
column_count = ws.max_column
   
def get_employee_list():
    employee_list = []
    # get an array of players from the sheet provided
    for row in range(2, row_count + 1):
        employee_list_single: list[Any] = [ws.cell(row, 1).value]

        for col in range(2, column_count + 1):
            char = get_column_letter(col)
            employee_details: list(Any) = [ws[char + str(1)].value, ws[char + str(row)].value]
            employee_list_single.append(employee_details)
        employee_list.append(employee_list_single)

    # print(employee_list)
    employee_list_arr = np.array(employee_list, dtype=object)
    # print(employee_list_arr)
    np.save('employeeList.npy', employee_list_arr)
    return


get_employee_list()
employees_list = np.load('employeeList.npy', allow_pickle=True)
```